# Internal Link is not working from IE

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, security, internet-explorer-11, tls

In my IE TLS 1.1 ,1.2 and 1.3 are enabled, but I am not able to access sites from IE and with same security setup in chrome which takes from IE works fine, Can u let me know why it works on chrome and not work in IE.

Comment: Your question is too broad. What do you mean with "internal link"? Is it something accessible only from a LAN (office or home network)? Furthermore, what do you mean with "not working"? What result do you have with IE (site not reachable, error)?

Comment: I am trying to connect to Internal server

Comment: Its shows site cannot be reached

Answer (score 0):

There's tremendous lack of specific info here, but I'm going to suggest it's likely due to a unsafe [cipher suite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx) being used by the site (and by your install of Windows).

A while ago certain ciphers were determined to be unsafe and were rendered inoperable via a Windows/IE update. Attacks like the [POODLE and BEAST attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Attacks_against_TLS.2FSSL) take advantage of these weak cipher suites to get around TLS/SSL protections.

Internet Explorer uses the cipher suites built into Windows, Chrome and Firefox do not.

If the cipher suite is still being used/offered by the site, and your Windows/IE sill has that suite in it's list of accepted cipher suites, then you will run into this.

**The person running the site should fix their web server to not use those unsafe cipher suites**.  If that person is using IIS, they need to adjust the cipher suites in the Windows OS hosting IIS.

If that's not going to happen, then you need to remove the disabled ciphers form the cipher suite list on your computer, so that Windows doesn't try to use them.

For more info and a handy utility for removing/reordering the cipher suites, see [Nartac software's IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto).

For more info on figuring out which specific ciphers you're having troubles with, perhaps also check out these MS articles:

- [How to determine Cipher Suite between IE and IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2010/11/17/how-to-determine-cipher-suite-between-ie-and-iis/)
- [How to Determine the Cipher Suite for the Server and Client](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299520)